# how to make non primitive class member immutable

Tags: java, immutability

I have a small question here, Please tell me if even thinking this is right or not.

while making a class immutable i have a non primitive member. how can i make that member immutable.while in its own implementation it is not immutable eg

```
public Class A{
private final int  immutableInt;
private final String immutableString;
private final Employee toBeMadeImmutable

// individual getters

}
```

no if use the getter for "toBeMadeImmutable" i will get the object of it them i can do whatever with that object so it will be mutable, which is not required.

how can the immutability be achieved for non primitive member

Comment: `Employee` class must be immutable as well.

Comment: Does `final` not accomplish that?

Comment: @jhobbie no, it means that `toBeMadeImmutable` reference cannot be changed but the data that this reference holds can still be changed.

Comment: Just what TheLostMind says. In order to do so, each variable within the object must be final.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't provide inbuilt support for immutability.

You can make fields immutable by making their `setters private` and exposing only their `getters as public` methods.

Additionally, immutability cannot be achieved by declaring a variable as final. 
by declaring a variable as final, you are specifying that you will not change the object to which the reference is pointing. You can still change the state of the object (by changing its fields) to which the reference is pointing.

Comment: No need to yell. No need to format non-code as code.

Comment: You can strong the text by wrapping it using double * **like this**. If you use a single * to wrap the text *it will be italic*.

Comment: -1 The OP has stated his worry about exposing the reference via a getter and that the caller could use that reference to change the state. I believe the clone answers better answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

If one of your fields is not immutable it's going to be difficult to make your object immutable. It's possible to get close if you make a defensive copy:

```
Employee getEmployee() {
    return new Employee(toBeMadeImmutable);
}
```

Where the constructor makes a new Employee with the same values.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in this case is provide a clone of toBeMadeImmutable, so that nobody can modify the original Employee